# Help solving a differential equation using Green function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

By using the appropriate green function, I need to find the function ${\rm u}\left(x,t\right)$ that solves the equation
$$
{\rm u}_{xx}\left(x,t\right) + {\rm u}_{t}\left(x,t\right)
=
{\rm f}\left(x,t\right)\quad
\mbox{in the domain}\quad \left\{x > 0\,,\ t < \infty\right\}$$

Boundary conditions: ${\rm u}\left(0,t\right) = 0\,,\quad{\rm u}\left(x,0\right) =0\,,
\quad{\rm u}\left(x,t\right) = 0$ at $x \to \infty$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.